# Avoid duplicate query with prefilled ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a `Form` with a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` which [queryset is generated at Form instanciation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships). I also want the three first choices to be initially checked. Here is my code:

```
class DeliveryForm(forms.Form):

    content = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Contenu"), validators=[
            MinLengthValidator(20),
            MaxLengthValidator(5000),
        ], widget=Wysiwyg)

    sponsors = DeliverySponsorsField(
        label=_("Commanditaires"), validators=[
            MaxLengthValidator(3),
        ], error_messages={
            'max_length': _(
                "Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 3 commanditaires."),
        }, queryset=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        quote_request = kwargs.pop('quote_request')
        suitable_sponsors = Sponsor.objects.all().suitable_for_quote_request(
            quote_request)

        initial = kwargs.pop('initial', None) or {}
        if 'content' not in initial:
            initial['content'] = quote_request.description
        if 'sponsors' not in initial:
            initial['sponsors'] = suitable_sponsors[:3]

        kwargs['initial'] = initial

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['sponsors'].queryset = suitable_sponsors
```

`DeliverySponsorsField` is a subclass of `ModelMultipleChoiceField` that enables me to display a complex widget:

```
class DeliverySponsorsRenderer(CheckboxFieldRenderer):
    outer_html = '<ul{id_attr} class="media-list">{content}</ul>'
    inner_html = '<li class="media">[...]</li>'

    def render(self):
        id_ = self.attrs.get('id')
        output = []
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            choice_value, sponsor = choice
            widget = self.choice_input_class(self.name, self.value,
                                             self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)
            output.append({
                'x': sponsor.x, 'y': sponsor.y, 'z': sponsor.z, ...})

        content = format_html_join('\n', self.inner_html, output)
        # I have my own `format_html_join` function that handles keyword arguments
        return format_html(self.outer_html,
                           id_attr=format_html(' id="{}"', id_) if id_ else '',
                           content=content)

class DeliverySponsorsWidget(CheckboxSelectMultiple):
    renderer = DeliverySponsorsRenderer

class DeliverySponsorsField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    widget = DeliverySponsorsWidget

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj
```

This works like a charm.

Well, not exactly because the following lines evaluates the queryset:

```
initial['sponsors'] = suitable_sponsors[:3]
```

And the queryset is also evaluated afterwards to generate the possible choices. Though only one query would be sufficient (since `suitable_sponsors[:3]` is a subset of `suitable_sponsors`.

I tried to force the queryset evaluation with:

```
# Replaced
suitable_sponsors = Sponsor.objects.all().suitable_for_quote_request(
        quote_request)
# with
suitable_sponsors = list(
    Sponsor.objects.all().suitable_for_quote_request(quote_request))
```

However, `ModelMultipleChoiceField` complains about `queryset` not being a `QuerySet`. More accurately, it complains about `queryset.all` being undefined:

```
File "/home/antoine/.venvs/aladom_v6/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in get_renderer
  763.         choices = list(chain(self.choices, choices))

File "/home/antoine/.venvs/aladom_v6/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __iter__
  1105.         queryset = self.queryset.all()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/quotation/requalification/141369/deliver/
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'
```

Can I "easily" avoid querying the database twice while I could query it only once for this case?

Comment: Unless the extra query is causing performance problems, this might be a case of premature optimisation.

Comment: @Alasdair Sure, that's why I ask for a "simple" solution. The point is not to create an overweening machinery to avoid this extra query. If I can easily avoid it, good. If this require some exotic work, I'd rather keep the extra query.

Comment: @Antoine: "Give an inch and take a mile", you have to be vigilant with performance :) then again sometime you have to give in

Comment: No problem, my question was mainly for the sake of curiosity. I know I have much more important things to be concerned about. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing a query set to your field, you can provide a list of values to the selection box instead.

```
suitable_sponsors = Sponsor.objects.suitable_for_quote_request(quote_request)\
    .values_list('id', 'sponsor_name')

if 'sponsors' not in initial:
    initial['sponsors'] = [s.id for s in suitable_sponsors[:3]]

self.fields['sponsors'].choices = suitable_sponsors
```

you might have to change ModelMultipleChoiceField to MultipleChoiceField.

Comment: I'm actually using a custom subclass of `ModelMultipleChoiceField` that enables me to display a complex widget with more data than just the sponsor name. However, this looks like a good idea, I think I can subclass `MultipleChoiceField` rather than `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like using a `MultipleChoiceField` or `TypedMultipleChoiceField` would complexify my custom field more than needed.

Comment: Can you try self.fields['sponsors'].widget.choices = suitable_sponsors? i don't know if this is a valid syntax.

Comment: `TypeError: 'Sponsor' object is not iterable`. :P

Comment: It was expected, `choices` is supposed to be a list of tuples, not a list of model instances.